# Open every file in a folder and deliminate the data using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for an excel code which can open every file in a folder (the extensions are not the same - they have a date extension) as a text and deliminate it. After I want to work with this tables.

I actually trying to get some codes from here, but most of them are for xls or without deliminations.

Can anyone give me a skelet code how could I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will loop through files in a specified folder (it opens a dialog box to choose folder)

```
Dim sPath As String
Dim sFil As String
Dim FolderPath As String
   Dim diaFolder As FileDialog

   ' Open the file dialog
   Set diaFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    diaFolder.AllowMultiSelect = False
    diaFolder.Show
    FolderPath = diaFolder.SelectedItems(1)

     ' Cycle through spreadsheets in selected folder

sPath = FolderPath & "\" 'location of files

sFil = Dir(sPath & "*.xls") 'change or add formats
Do While sFil <> "" 'will start LOOP until all files in folder sPath have been looped            through


Set oWbk = Workbooks.Open(sPath & "\" & sFil) 'opens the file
' do something

oWbk.Close True
sFil = Dir

Loop
```

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: Ok, I understand this code and I can change it to my requirement, but there is only one thing is not working, after when I open a raw text format how can I coded the "text to column" after the open? This doesn't want to work to me